# If $\lim d(x_n,s) = d(x,s)$ for every $s$ in a dense subset, prove that $\lim x_n= x$.

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $S\subset M$ dense subset. Given a sequence $(x_n)$ in $M$, suppose that for some $x\in M$ $\lim d(x_n,s) = d(x,s)$ for every $s\in S$. Prove that $\lim x_n = x$.

My attempt: Since $S$ is dense in $M$ and $x\in M$, it follows that $x = \lim a_n$ for some sequence $(a_n)$ in $S$. It is given that $\lim d(x_n,s) = d(x,s)$ for every $s\in S$. So,  in particular we can evaluate for all elements of $(a_n)$. Therefore, noting that the metric function $d$ is continuous,  we obtain $\lim d(x_n,a_n) = d(x,a_n) =  d(\lim a_n,a_n) = \lim d(a_n,a_n) = 0.$

But this only proves that $\lim d(x_n,a_n) = 0$. How can I proceed to the conclusion that $\lim x_n = x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written isn't quite correct because you have two sequences indexed by $n$, but you are only taking the limit of one of them. Every $k$ satisfies
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,a_k) = d(x,a_k),
$$
so by the triangle inequality, we have
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} d(x_n,x)
\le \limsup_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,a_k) + d(a_k,x)
= 2d(x,a_k).
$$
Since this holds for every $k$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}d(x,a_k)=0$, we conclude
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,x)=0.
$$

Comment: Why did you chose to evaluate the $\lim\sup$?

Comment: @math.h At that moment in the proof, it is not known whether $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,x)$ exists. However the limit supremum always exists, and if I can show that it must be zero, then (by the fact that distances are positive), we know that the limit exists and is zero.

Comment: Perfect care, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}d (x_n,a_n)=0$$

means that if $(a_n) $ converges, $(x_n) $ will also converge and to the same limit, since we have

$$0\le d (x_n,x)\le d (x_n,a_n)+d (a_n,x) $$

Answer (score 1):

for all $s\in S$

$$\lim d(x_n,x) \le d(x,s)+\lim d(x_n,s) = 2d(x,s)$$

But by density there exists $s_n\in S$ with
$$\lim s_n, =x$$ that is 
$$ \lim d(s_n,x) = 0 $$
so in particular for $s_n$,
$$\lim d(x_n,x) \le 2d(x,s_n)$$ for all n . letting  n to $\to\infty$ we get
$$\lim d(x_n,x) \le\lim 2d(x,s_n) =0$$ 
that is 
$$\lim d(x_n,x)=0$$

Comment: you mean $\lim d(s_n,x) = 0$, right?

Comment: yes of course n or j it does not matter

Comment: Ok I have put n in the edit. now have a look

Comment: I mean at the fourth and sixth line. From $\lim s_n = x$ you concluded that $\lim d(s_n,s) =0$. But i guess that you mean $\lim d(s_n,x) = 0$.

Comment: ooo ya thanks I corrected it